# Automatic sign of Transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, metamask, dapp-development, signature

Is there any secure solution(without exposing a Private key of the user) to automatically sign transactions, which are requested from a DApp, so that user doesn't have to sign each of them manually? I know that in the web3 API exists something like this:

```
let signedTransaction = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, PRIVATE_KEY);
```

But Private key is exposed here, which is in my opinion a security issue. Am I wrong?

Comment: You could keep the private key in local storage

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think it's still a security issue, is it somehow possible without using any private key in the browser?

Comment: You could use a proxy contract that you have control over and the user can trigger transactions through authenticated REST calls but then you are in charge of keeping the private key secure.

Comment: At Pegasys we are working on a project called EthSigner that acts like a proxy for your tx and sign them but your dapp and node will never have to deal with the keys. You may have a look at it : https://docs.ethsigner.pegasys.tech/